# I am unable to use spawnlp in python 2.7.2

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am playing around with [entangled](http://entangled.sourceforge.net/) which makes use of [os.spawnlp](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.spawnlp). I am currently running Python 2.7.2.

Here's the error I am getting.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "create_network.py", line
>   47, in 
>       nodes.append(os.spawnlp(os.P_NOWAIT, 'python', 'python py', str(startPort))) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
>   'spawnlp'

How do I go about solving this issue? There doesn't seem to be any indication that `spawnlp` was removed/deleted since it was first added in version 1.6.

I've already re-downloaded the windows python installer and ran it with the repair option. The only thing I can think it might be is that this computer is 64bit and the python version is 32bit... I don't think that's the problem but that's the only thing I can think of...

Lastly, `its recommended to use the subprocess module rather than the os.spawn*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.spawnlp) it states that

> spawnlp(), spawnlpe(), spawnvp() and spawnvpe() are not available on Windows. spawnle() and spawnve() are not thread-safe on Windows; we advise you to use the subprocess module instead

You have to indeed use another module to create subprocesses.

Comment: Nice catch, that's what I get for being lazy and skimming the docs.